# Detecting a specific string with regex in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7, python-re

I have a csv file with below string structure:

```
Modem Switch (MMA-213-MML-NW-Match-New Year)(32655)(12532)
Modem Switch3 (MMA-1234-431-NW-Match-New Month)(32655)(12532)
Modem Switch3 (MMA-1234-431-NW-Match-New1 Month)(32655)(12532)
Modem Switch3 (MMA-1234-431-NW-Match-New Month 2)(32655)(12532)
....
```

I want to get any string which comes after Match:
For example the expected result shared as below:

```
New Year
New Month
New1 Month
New Month 2
```

with below code it is not possible to get my relative string:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(Match-)(\w+)', inp, flags=re.I)
```

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'\bMatch-([^)]+)', inp, flags=re.I)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
import re
inp = "Modem Switch3 (MMA-1234-431-NW-Match-New Month)(32655)(12532)"
matches = re.findall(r'Match-(.+?)\)', inp, flags=re.I)
```

gives

```
['New Month']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also match all following word characters with spaces in between, and use a single capturing group.

```
\bMatch-(\w+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\w+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cRGj8K/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7uZ0xY%5D)

```
import re
 
regex = r"\bMatch-(\w+(?:[^\S\r\n]+\w+)*)"
 
s = ("Modem Switch (MMA-213-MML-NW-Match-New Year)(32655)(12532)\n"
    "Modem Switch3 (MMA-1234-431-NW-Match-New Month)(32655)(12532)\n"
    "Modem Switch3 (MMA-1234-431-NW-Match-New1 Month)(32655)(12532)\n"
    "Modem Switch3 (MMA-1234-431-NW-Match-New Month 2)(32655)(12532)")
 
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['New Year', 'New Month', 'New1 Month', 'New Month 2']
```

Or to match all after `Match-` between parenthesis, you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any character except `(` and `)`

```
\([^()]*\bMatch-([^()]+)\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rv2bD1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'(?<=Match-)[^()]+', inp, flags=re.I)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/fikuyb/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Match-                   'Match-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^()]+                   any character except: '(', ')' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
```

[Python code](https://tio.run/##pdCxCsIwGATgvU/x06UJNkKS1skijoLp4iAiCsWmNtAmIQaKTx8DXdRR1@O@4c4@fW80D0GN1jgPTiZKW6ggTVNhWjnCYVL@1gMSYksY5USIPamPRDQxJbWc4CQbhxFnq7LEiLKSM5y8Uz5bynhBCk4/sTDa979q@h@fNbAvH5cn1intkZPLTum2GQbkMrRZVzPF5yvCl0WWQ7wqh25o7o8qdncYh/AC):

```py
import re
inp = """Modem Switch (MMA-213-MML-NW-Match-New Year)(32655)(12532)
Modem Switch3 (MMA-1234-431-NW-Match-New Month)(32655)(12532)
Modem Switch3 (MMA-1234-431-NW-Match-New1 Month)(32655)(12532)
Modem Switch3 (MMA-1234-431-NW-Match-New Month 2)(32655)(12532)"""
print(re.findall(r'(?<=Match-)[^()]+', inp, flags=re.I))
```

**Results**: `['New Year', 'New Month', 'New1 Month', 'New Month 2']`